# Django models, one to many relationship with back reference [how]

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlalchemy

I have a database that I filled with objects using SQLAlchemy, but I cannot figure out how to make the models in Django.

I need the Show objects to have arrays of Episode objects via a relationship. In the database all the Episode objects have a 'show_title' column and all the Show objects have 'episodes'

the objects look like this with *SQLAlchemy*,

```
   class AlphaShow(Base) :    
    __tablename__ = 'show' 
    title = Column(UnicodeText, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(UnicodeText)
    image = Column(UnicodeText)
    episodes = relationship("Episode", backref="show")
    def __init__(self,_meta) :
        self.title = _meta.title
        self.image = _meta.image
        self.description = _meta.description

class Episode (Base) : #was without base 
    __tablename__= 'episode'
    title = Column(UnicodeText, primary_key = True)
    link = Column(UnicodeText)
    show_title = Column(UnicodeText, ForeignKey('show.title'))

    def __init__(self, _title, _link) :
        self.title = _title
        self.link = _link
```

How would I make the models in *Django*? 
I tried this but it doesn't work,

```
class Shows(models.Model) :
    episodes = [] 
    title = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()  
    image = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'shows'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  


class Episode(models.Model) :

    title = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    link = models.TextField()  
    show_title = models.ForeignKey(Shows)

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'episodes'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I guess what I'm missing is, what is the Django equivalent to SQLAlchemy's

```
episodes = relationship("Episode", backref="show")
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
class Shows(models.Model) :
    title = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()  
    image = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'shows'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  


class Episode(models.Model) :
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, related_name="episodes")
    title = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    link = models.TextField()  
    show_title = models.ForeignKey(Shows)

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'episodes'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: So this seems to work, but not really, when I try and say 

`s = Shows.objects.all() 
print(s[0].episodes[0].title)`

it returns an error saying 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing??

Comment: What does `s[0]` give you? What does `s[0].episodes` give you?

Comment: s[0].episodes gives me a RelatedManger object, I read that I can just use the .all() instead of treating it like a list, but then it gives me an error "relation "episodes" does not exist," I think the problem is Django is adding _id to everything, so instead of show_title it becomes show_title_id

Comment: s[0] gives me the title of the show, as it should.... keep getting this error that the relationship doesn't exist even after removing the '_id' don't understand it

Comment: Can you show me the structure of your table? And yes, you have to do `s[0].episodes.all()[0].title`